# Can SagePay's callback be validated to prevent hacking?

Tags: security, validation, callback, opayo

SagePay's form callback can be hacked by re-using the success URL that the user is directed to upon a successful transaction. This can create all sorts of problems with duplicate transactions, fake transactions etc.

You can check for a duplicate VPSTxId, but these can be generated anew by hacking around the crypt parameter of the callback URL.

The crypt parameter can also be manipulated to generate a different "Amount" field.

I have not tested what other field values can be changed by hacking the callback URL crypt parameter.

Is there any way (as per PayPal's IPN validation) of doing a double-check callback to SagePay to ensure that the transaction is new and unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always redirect a user from a success URL.
I personally use a fulfil page (success url), and a thank you page. On the fulfil page, you should obviously only ever process a transaction once (based on the transaction id), and you can store crypt sent with a transaction. The crypt will have to be valid and is only possible to encrypt if you have the encryption key.
So hacking would be extremely difficult unless you are being very security lax, and the hacker would have to know your encryption key to even begin trying to hack it.

Alternatively, you should use the server integration, so that the communications are server-server, not client-server. There is little difference between form and server.

10 immutable laws of security
http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc722487.aspx

Comment: Good idea to redirect away from the fulfil page but wouldn't it be easy to get the Success URL if you tracked it through say Fiddler? Also it is easy to hack to the crypt without knowing the encryption password. Example: try knocking a few letters/numbers off the crypt, then decrypting it. It still decrypts fine, only the Amount field, txID field (maybe others) can be changed by doing this. Do you know if there is any callback validation available with SagePay forms, as per PayPal?

Comment: You can use their Reporting & Admin API I suppose, but you may aswel just integrate via server and save yourself the hassle. But back to your point about decrypting, if you change the encrypted string then decrypt it, it should error as it would be valid base64 encoding when it comes to decrypt it. As I said before though, just ensure that you only ever process an success url once. If you arrive at the page with the same transaction reference, throw an error :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your post.  In general we encourage clients to use Server integration where they can. We also constantly monitor transactions for suspicious behaviour and proactively contact our customers if we suspect any malicious activity.

We recommend customers make sure that they’re using the latest version of our integration protocol which is currently v3. Get the [latest integration documents](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document).

As Dan suggests you could use the [Reporting and Admin API](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/server-integration-documents) to validate that a transaction does indeed exist on the Sage Pay side but having an additional validation mechanism (like PayPal's IPN) is something we will actively explore.

If you'd like us to update you on this, then please get in contact with our customer services team at support@sagepay.com or 0845 111 44 55.

Sage Pay Support